# Was ist ein "ethnisches Milieu"?

Tags: meaning

Ich habe folgendes Zitat aus einer deutschen Tageszeitung entnommen:

> Das Verhalten sei zwar moralisch zweifelhaft, aber nicht strafbar. Das
>   Verhältnis der drei Männer und der Frau zueinander müsse noch
>   überprüft werden, alle vier stammten „**aus einem ethnischen Milieu**“.

Kann mir jemand erklären, was unter "ethnischem Milieu" zu verstehen ist?

Comment: Kannst Du einen Link zu dem Artikel hinzufügen?

Comment: [Mann legt mitten in Hamburg Frauenleiche auf Gehsteig ab](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/gesellschaft/kriminalitaet/hamburg-mann-legt-leiche-einer-frau-auf-gehweg-ab-16479596.html). Allem Anschein nach entstammt das Zitat einer Pressemitteilung der Polizei Hamburg.

Comment: Ich finde die Frage unbefriedigend. Es wird ein offenbar schlecht formulierter Satz präsentiert, und dann wird gefragt, was die misslungene Formulierung heißen soll. Wo kommen wir da hin, wenn wir hier anfangen, missratenen Sätzen Sinn zuzuinterpretieren? - Eine bessere Frage wäre: Wie könnte man das (vermutlich) Gemeinte besser formulieren?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich finde es durchaus legitim, nach der Bedeutung von etwas zu fragen, das man in der Zeitung gelesen hat. Selbst wenn deine Einschätzung als misslungene Formulierung zutreffen sollte, muss das ja nicht für jeden sofort ersichtlich sein.

Answer (score 2):

Die Besonderheit des Vorfalls (es geht um das Ablegen einer Leiche auf dem Gehweg) erregt wohl das Bedürfnis, eine Erklärung zu finden. Ich denke, der Polizeisprecher, dem das Zitat zugeschrieben wird, möchte das Verhalten der Personen auf deren Herkunft zurückführen, ohne dies direkt zu sagen. Der Verschleierungsversuch ist insofern verständlich, als eine solche Zurückführung Merkmale von Rassismus aufweist.

*Ethnie* ist Volksgruppe im weiten Sinn, also nicht ethnische Minderheit, sondern Gruppe, die durch Erzählungen von gemeinsamer Abstammung und Kultur konstituiert wird.

Unter *Milieu* dagegen versteht man in der Soziologie eine Gruppe, die durch gemeinsame Einstellungen und Lebensweisen konstituiert wird. Ich muß dabei zuerst an die [Sinus-Milieus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinus-Milieus) denken; für einen Polizisten liegt vielleicht eine negative Interpretation im Sinne von *kriminelles Milieu* näher (aber dazu gleich mehr).

Jedenfalls sind die zwei Begriffe orthogonal zueinander: Die beteiligten Personen werden entlang zweier Achsen klassifiziert. Da sich alle Menschen auf diese Weise klassifizieren lassen, ist *aus einem ethnischen Milieu* zunächst inhaltsleer. Aber durch die Nichtnennung der Ausprägungen werden diese dann als negativ interpretiert: Die Beteiligten gehören einer Ethnie und einem Milieu an, von denen Schlechtes zu erwarten ist.

Comment: Oder kurz: Weil sich herumgesprochen hat, dass man "Ausländer mit dunkler Haut" nicht mehr sagen soll, sagt man jetzt "Angehörige ethnischer Minderheiten". Ja, das ist jetzt etwas polemisch, aber es trifft die kommunikative Wirklichkeit im deutschen Sprachraum gut. Der Polizeisprecher hat darüber hinaus das Wort noch völlig gedankenlos verwendet.

Comment: Man könnte auch meinen, *ethnisch* sei positiv besetzt, oder zumindest neutral, und schwäche *Milieu* insofern für die Autoren ab, da die Interpretation beim Leser liegt. *Miliö* impliziert teils auch *präkär*, also nicht unbedingt *kriminell* und in diesem Fall eventuell *rechtsunkundig*. Und da Verbotsirrtum sträflichkeit ausschließen würde, wäre das ggf. straffrei, wobei das Gericht zu entscheiden hätte während es die Polizei in der Regel wenig interessiert. Ob "nicht strafbar" so gemeint war oder ob gar kein Straftatbestand verwirklicht wurde, erschließt sich mir mangels Kontext nicht.

Comment: @Vectory  Kannst du ein Beispiel aus der Sprachpraxis des Deutschen nennen, wo "Ethnos" positiv konnotiert ist? Mir fällt keines ein. Selbst "ethnische Säuberungen" sind ja nichts Schönes, obwohl hier "ethnisch" in der Tat jedenfalls nicht böse gegenüber den Opfern gemeint ist.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ethnologen, Ethnologiestudenten, usw. - gerade weil das Wort neutral ist flüchtet sich der Sprecher ja wahrscheinlich in diese Wortwahl. Das problematische an ethnischen Säuberungen sind ja die sog. Säuberungen.

Answer (score 1):

Wohlwollend interpretiert stammen die Täter nach dieser Äußerung aus einem Milieu, dessen Charakteristikum die Ethnie ist. Es gibt auch berufliche Milieus, regionale Milieus, Altersmilieus, soziale Milieus - hier teilen die Täter offenbar ihre Abstammung.

Ob das stimmt und ob es relevant ist, sind ganz andere Fragen.

Answer (score 0):

Möglicherweise hat der Autor dieser fragwürdigen Zeilen gemeint:

> Alle vier entstammen einem außereuropäischen Kulturkreis

Ansonsten kann man nur spekulieren: Vermutlich wollte der Autor seiner Auffassung Ausdruck geben, dass die vier Personen "keine Deutschen" seien oder "Ausländer", und jedenfalls "anders als wir".

Dass alle diese Formulierungen fragwürdig sind, hat allerdings selbst der Autor erkannt, und darum hat er sich bemüht, eine Formulierung zu finden, die neutral klingt. Dass ihm das dermaßen misslungen ist (wie Antwortgeber David Vogt treffend ausführt), macht den Versuch wahlweise komisch oder tragisch.

Der Autor hat offenbar den Begriff "Ethnos" oder "ethnisch" nicht verstanden, sondern hält ihn für gleichbedeutend mit dem, was er (stillschweigend) als "Ausländer" sieht. Leben wir im 19. Jahrhundert, würde er vermutlich von "Wilden" sprechen.

Doch Spekulationen zu den kognitiven Unfällen, die zu bescheuerten Formulierungen führen, sind eigentlich nicht das Thema dieses Forums. Da müsste man wohl eher ins Psychologie-Forum gehen, oder vielleicht ins Alltagsrassissmus-Forum.

Comment: Die anderen sind "ethnisch", "wir" natürlich nicht. Auf Englisch hat es diese Bedeutung von *ethnic* in die Wörterbücher geschafft ([1c](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ethnic)). Ein Beispiel [hier](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4169202) die Gegenüberstellung von spanischem und "ethnischem" Namen.

Comment: @DavidVogt   Herrje! - Ein weiteres schönes Beispiel für Mangel an Sprachbewusstsein und Sprachkritik beim Ethnos der angloamerikanischen Durchschnittssprachbenutzer. Klar, "ethnic" ist etwas immer dann, wenn es in bunte Tücher gehüllt ist und komische Mützen trägt.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, ja, das ist hier nicht der richtige Zeitpunkt für derlei Diskusionsanstöße. Ich finde es jedenfalls anstößig, und nehme mir daher auch nicht heraus, da hinein zu interpretieren, was genau gemeint gewesen sein könnte. Viel mehr wollte ich oben bei Davids Antwort auch nicht sagen; Eine durchweg positive Verwendung fällt mir momentan nicht ein. So oder so scheint es, ich wollte nichts gesagt haben. Vielleicht verbinde ich *ethnie* unbegründet mit *ethos*; vielleicht ist das *-n-* auch von einem Negationspartikel--denke nicht, werde deshalb nicht *noch mal* nachschlagen

Comment: Der Anteil negativer Partikel im letzten Kommentar ist hoch; Sentiment-Analyse würde das als abwertend interpretieren, ggf bzgl des Inhalts der Frage. Ich versuchs nochmal konstruktiv (aller guten Dinge …): Das Thema ist komplex, daher interessant; kurz gesagt: brisant. Es bedarf weiterer Nachforschung und Aufklärung. *Ethnologie* ist positiv besetzt (ich Kenne die Besetzung zwar nicht persönlich). *Ethnie* sowie *Ethos* werden beide von PIE \*swe- abgeleitet, mit \*-dh-no- bzw k.A. (lt. etymonline; hätte *schwören* können, *et-[ymologie]* bedeute "echt").--Na das ist doch etwas.